# Multiple delegates and BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events

If I want to fire an event containing multiple event handlers in an async manner where the multiple delegates are called in a synchronous manner but the processing of all of the handlers is doesn't block execution on the current thread, how would I do that?

I've tried the following, but throws an exception because of multiple delegates

```
public void Example()
{
    SomethingHappened += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("A");
    SomethingHappened += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("B");

    // Exception here because of multiple delegates
    SomethingHappened?.BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, x => ((EventHandler)x.AsyncState).EndInvoke(x), SomethingHappened);
}
```

Comment: So you want to execute the handlers in a defined order, but parallel to the thread that fired the event?

Comment: Use `Task.Run`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere correct, so basically just a way of getting BeginInvoke to work with multiple delegates.

Comment: @Evk can you provide an example?

Comment: `var handler = SomethingHappened; if (handler != null) Task.Run(() => handler(this, EventArgs.Empty))`. Of course you also need to catch exceptions inside that task so that they don't go unnoticed.

Comment: @Evk can you provide an answer with a solution with how to catch exceptions too? Then I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Just don't use a primitive that requires you to catch exceptions.  Gross mishaps need to stay gross.  Like ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty));

Comment: @HansPassant can you clarify "Just don't use a primitive that requires you to catch exceptions"?

Comment: "Do something meaningful".  Nobody knows what that might mean or how to do that properly.  It just can't be done properly, the exception occurs in code that you know next to nothing about.  The point of events.  The worst thing about catching an exception is having to deal with it, the best thing about not catching an exception is that it cannot randomly make the program misbehave.

Comment: @HansPassant would you mind putting that as an answer?